# Java with Git Bash

Tags: java, git-bash

How can I use Git Bash with Java? Before I got Git Bash I used the windows command line to run commands like java file.java and javac file... How do I use Git Bash for those simple purposes?

Comment: What errors occurs when you run `java file.java` in bash?

Comment: It says that it is not a recognized bash command.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Git Bash is set up only for Git and basic file operations. It won't import, for example, your Widows PATH variables which tell it where to find `java`.

I infer you're running a Windows machine (or you could use normal Bash directly), and you want to run *NIX style shell. Using Git Bash would work but is sloppy: You'd have to add the path to your Java runtime manually with a command such as `export PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/java/binary`.

If you're mostly interested in running a *NIX style shell, rather than using Git, the right way would be to use either the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), which gives you an almost perfect Linux emulator, or something like [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/).

Tip: If you go down the Windows Subsystem for Linux route, you'll want the following command to move to your Windows file system: `cd /mnt/c/`.

All the best.